# NodeJS function execute order

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

Just start learn Node and trying to build an app.

Right now in my route file I'm trying to connect to mysql and get the major of the user and then used it to do other stuff. However when I execute the webpage the console shows that the second log execute earlier than the first one. I guess this might because Node is Async?

```
exports.list = function(req, res){
req.getConnection(function(err,connection){
   /* find user's major */
    var user_major = (function() {
        connection.query('SELECT major FROM user WHERE user_id=' + req.params.id, function (err, row) {
            if (err) {
                console.log("Error Selecting : %s ", err);
            }
            console.log('Test inside function: '+ row[0].major);
            return row[0].major;
        });
    })();
    console.log("Test outside: " + user_major);

    res.render('main/main',{page_title:'USER MAJOR', data: user_major});
    });
};
```

Terminal log:

```
Test outside: undefined
GET /main/1 304 353.737 ms - -
Test inside function: COEN
```

Comment: That's right, it's because it's async. Have you ever worked with ajax? It's a similar idea.

Comment: You need to understand how async programming works. `Test outside` gets executed first.

Comment: If you want to make your async code easier to write, check out https://github.com/Sage/streamlinejs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the others have pointed out in the comments, Node.js is asynchronous. You can't just return data from a function, it has to be returned in a callback.

I'd rewrite it as follows:

```
exports.list = function(req, res, next) {
    req.getConnection(function(err, connection) {
        if (err) return next(err);
            /* find user's major */
        var user_major = function(id, callback) {
            connection.query('SELECT major FROM user WHERE user_id=' + id, function(err, row) {
                if (err) {
                    return callback("Error Selecting : %s ", err);
                }
                callback(null, row[0].major);
            });
        };

        user_major(req.params.id, function(error, major) {
            if (error) return next(error);
            res.render('main/main', {
                page_title: 'USER MAJOR',
                data: major
            });
        });

    });
};
```

Comment: I realize you were just reworking the OP's code, but this should be checking to see if an error occurred in the `req.getConnection()` callback.

Comment: @MattBrowne I wouldn't expect the OP to copy and paste my example into production code, but I've added it anyway. Thanks :)

Comment: Thank you all!! I spend a few hours and study the concept of asynchronous. It's really tricky but now I kind of get it.

Answer (score -1):

You are facing the problem because when the call stack reaches console.log, the value is yet to be returned, since node js is async. Callbacks are used to call back a callback function with a result of the async function.

```
    exports.list = function(req, res){
    req.getConnection(function(err,connection){
       /* find user's major */

      var callback = function(user_major){
     console.log("1 Test outside: " + user_major);
     res.render('main/main',{page_title:'USER MAJOR', data: user_major});
     }

        var db_call_for_user_major = (function(callback) { 
            connection.query('SELECT major FROM user WHERE user_id=' + req.params.id, function (err, row) {
                if (err) {
                    console.log("Error Selecting : %s ", err);
                }
                console.log('test inside function: '+ row[0].major);
                return callback(row[0].major);
            });
        })();

        });
    };
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I like the way you name the db function. Really useful =)